# How to search in rails from two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, search-engine

I have two models `Lcities` and `lservices`

```
class Lcity < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :Lservices
attr_accessible  :lname , :lcode , :lexperience , :lrating , :llocation
end
```

and

```
class Lservice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :Lcity   
attr_accessible  :lcode , :lscode , :lcharg , :lname
end
```

I want to get the data by searching on `llocation` of Lcities and `lname` of Lservice

Comment: setup association between them and use `joins` method

Comment: seems you posted a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894160/search-on-select-tag-in-rails

Comment: yesh i have posted..do you have answer?