# Search on select_tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, full-text-search, html-select

I have three models `Lcities` and `lservices` and `search`

```
class Lcity < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :Lservices
attr_accessible  :lname , :lcode , :lexperience , :lrating , :llocation
end
```

and

```
class Lservice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :Lcity   
attr_accessible  :lcode , :lscode , :lcharg , :lname
end

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city , :services
end
```

After submitting in `Search form` i want the all the `lname` from the Lcities model i know the sql query but how to apply on **Rails**

```
>select lname from Lcity where llocation.Lcity = lname.Lservice
```

`form_for search`

```
 <%= form_for (@search) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:city, city_for_select, :prompt => 'Select City') %>
 <%=f. select(:service, service_for_select, :prompt => 'Select Services') %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your symbols have to be downcased:

```
has_many :lservices
```

and

```
belongs_to :lcity
```

Second, your SQL is slightly right-to-left... Also, it makes little to no sense. However, to satisfy the custommer, it should be (mind the plural for tables):

```
select lname from lcites,lservices where lcites.llocation = lservices.lname
```

For your query:

```
Lcity.joins(:lservices).where("lservices.lname = lcites.llocation")
```

Not sure what kind of results you're expecting, but the answer matches your question.